# Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network, opencv

I'm making eye colour recognizing neural network. I need to make photos RGB, but I get this error:

Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found

This my code:

```
DATADIR = "/content/drive/My Drive/ForpythonEyes"

CATEGORIES = ["BlueEyes", "BrawnEyes"]

for category in CATEGORIES:  # do brawn and blue eyes
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to eyes
    for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image 
        img_array = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.UMat(os.path.join(path,img)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # convert to array
        plt.imshow(img_array,)  # graph it
        plt.show()  # display

        break  
    break
```

This is the full error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-a65ab6652084> in <module>()
     13     path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
     14     for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
---> 15         img_array = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.UMat(os.path.join(path,img)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # convert to array
     16         plt.imshow(img_array,)  # graph it
     17         plt.show()  # display!

TypeError: Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error message, and read it carefully. It should give you a hint *which function* is missing an argument. The solution should be as simple as *providing it*.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution when I change code:

```
for category in CATEGORIES:  # do brawn and blue eyes
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to eyes
    for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image
        img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
        img_array = img  # convert to array
        plt.imshow(img_array)  # graph it
        plt.show()  # display
        break  
    break
```